# How to draw the Poincaré patch of ${AdS_3}$?

Tags: general-relativity, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

My main reference for this question are [these notes](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~kurthi/Physics.html) (maximally symmetric spaces.pdf) by Kurt Hinterbichler. I'm using Global Coordinates:
\begin{align}
x^0&=\sec{R}\cos\tau\\
x^1&=\sec{R}\sin\tau\\
x^2&=\tan{R}\cos\theta\\
x^3&=\tan{R}\sin\theta\\
\end{align}
with $\tau\in[0,2\pi)$, $R\in[0,\pi/2)$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$, and Poincaré coordinates:
\begin{align}x^0&=\frac{1}{2u}\left[1+u^2-t^2+(z^3)^2\right]\\
x^1&=\frac{t}{2}\\
x^2&=\frac{1}{2u}\left[1-u^2+t^2-(z^3)^2\right]\\
x^3&=\frac{{z}^3}{u}
\end{align}
with ${u\in\mathbb{R}^+}$ and ${z^3,t\in\mathbb{R}}$. This way, relating the coordinates, I find that
$$u=\frac{\cos{R}}{\cos\tau+\sin{R}\cos\theta},\hspace{0.25in}t=\frac{\sin\tau}{\cos\tau+\sin{R}\cos\theta},\hspace{0.25in}z^3=\frac{\sin{R}\sin\theta_1}{\cos\tau+\sin{R}\cos\theta_1}$$
and what I want to do is to reproduce Figure 25 in the notes. I somehow figured that since this patch cover only ${x^0+x^2>0}$, then maybe the plot is simply the region
$$\cos\tau+\sin{R}\cos\theta>0$$
so I made the plot in Mathematica **(*)** and got this:
[image: Poincaré patch of $AdS_3$?]

which is a bit different from Figure 25 in the notes or the drawings usually found in the literature, like this:

[image]

or like this in Wikipedia:

[image]

So how should the Poincaré patch of ${AdS_3}$ be drawn? Might it be a software issue from Mathematica? I've noticed that sometimes the edges doesn't fill completely because of them being boundaries, like with Minkowski's diagram:

[image]

So what is the issue here and how should the plot be done?

**(*)** These are the command lines I used in Mathematica:
[image]